# Access Violation DirectWrite

Tags: c++, access-violation, directwrite

I am using the DirectWrite API and I am implementing my own layout and text rendering engine. I have already created my `IDWriteTextLayout` object successfully. When I make the following call I receive an Access Violation error and I have no idea why:

```
DWRITE_LINE_METRICS m_lineMetrics;
UINT32 m_lineCount;

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
   m_textLayout->GetLineMetrics(&m_lineMetrics,31,&m_lineCount)
);
```

Comment: You promised that the first argument is a pointer to an array with 31 elements.  It is not, you've only got one.  Kaboom.

Comment: That is what I was thinking. The documentation is confusing for it. It says that when the function returns there will be a pointer to an array of DWRITE_LINE_METRICS structures. When I try to pass a pointer to an array with 31 elements it breaks the function signature

Comment: How would I pass a pointer to an array with 31 elements without breaking the signature

Comment: I figured it out. I was reading the documentation for the function wrong I guess. You can pass either a pointer to a  single DWRITE_LINE_METRICS structure or an array of DWRITE_LINE_METRICS structures. I can't answer my own question because I am a newb.

Comment: It's a pointer either way. The problem is that array it points to has to be large enough as second argument indicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I guess I was interpreting the documentation for the function incorrectly. You can pass either a pointer to a single DWRITE_LINE_METRICS structure or an array of DWRITE_LINE_METRICS structures.